# Python unittest from command line executes more than expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

i have a Python testcase. When run test from command line with following command, test results are present correct. it shows 2 test case:

```
python TestClassAddBasket.py
```

but, if run with following following command:

```
python -m unittest discover
```

it runs 2 times and show 4 testcase reult

TestClassAddBasket.py

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import unittest


class TestClassAddBasket(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_item_one(self):
        .....

    def test_item_two(self):
        ........
        ..........


manuelTextRunner(TestClassAddBasket)
```

my manuel text runner function is:

```
def manuelTextRunner(self, TestClassName):
    testnames = unittest.getTestCaseNames(TestClassName,'test_')
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTests([TestClassName(methodName) for methodName in testnames])
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

why i use `python -m unittest discover` because, there are many testcases and run all with one command.

so, what can cause to run test multiple? any error in my runner function?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__': ` - your call.

Comment: already, i tried that. from -m unittest command, it doesn't dedect that line because it is not __main__

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Test cases already starting with `test_` are run by unittest itself and my runner. I changed it to another prefix and it is solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `python -m unittest discover` will run your tests in `TestClassAddBasket.py`.

It seems likely `manuelTextRunner(TestClassAddBasket)` was called in `TestClassAddBasket.py` and ran your test code again.

Unless you need to run that test case manual I would remove it.